# using sed in git filter-branch to replace path in xml files

Tags: git, sed, git-filter-branch

I am trying to replace path using sed in git filter-branch command.
I have three similar files DOM.xml in 3 different folders.
example:

```
SAM20/sam/DOM.xml
SAM21/sam/DOM.xml
SAM22/sam/DOM.xml
```

Content in the above three DOM.xml are different.
Getting error after trying with the below command.

```
Proceeding with filter-branch...
Rewrite ce96e44a942bfdc26bd8aa6fa4407b4a88965bca (1/644) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
sed: can't read SAM22/sam/DOM.xml: No such file or directory
tree filter failed: sed -i -e 's|./old/path/in/sam|./new/path/in/sam|g' SAM22/sam/DOM.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Side note: you should show the actual `git filter-branch` command itself, not just its output.  Fortunately we can see from the error message that you are using the `--tree-filter` option (which is the right option here).

The problem is almost certainly the fact that the *first* commit in the repository *simply does not have these files*.  Your command requires that the file `SAM22/sam/DOM.xml` exist when that particular commit is checked out, and the *first* commit might have just a README, for instance, or lack the `SAM22/sam/DOM.xml` file while having `SAM20` and/or `SAM21` files.

If it's OK for several files to be missing, use a sequence that does nothing when the files are missing, and edits the files when they exist.  For instance:

```
if test -f SAM22/sam/DOM.xml; then
    sed -i -e 's|./old/path/in/sam|./new/path/in/sam|g' SAM22/sam/DOM.xml
fi
```

To keep yourself sane, you might wish to build the tree filter into a shell script that you can run with `sh /tmp/script` or similar, so that your Git command reads:

```
git filter-branch <various options> --tree-filter "sh /tmp/script" <more options>
```

This will be a little bit slower than including the entire set of commands in the command line, but `--tree-filter` is already so miserably slow that this probably won't be much worse.  To make things go *much* faster, consider using `git filter-repo` instead of `git filter-branch`.

Answer (score 0):

If your tree's got anything like a lot of files, you'll get better to much, much better results with an index filter, something like

```
for f in $(git ls-files ":(glob)SAM2[012]/sam/DOM.xml")
do
        updated=$(
                git show :$f \
                | sed "s,path/to/old/locn,path/to/new/locn,g" \
                | git hash-object -w --stdin --path=$f
        )
        git update-index --cacheinfo 100644,$updated,$f
done
```